# How to pass data to other window location in reactjs without using query string?

Tags: reactjs, cross-browser, cross-domain

How can we pass the data to other url which is published in other
domain without using query string. Right now I am passing the data as:

`window.location.assign('http://localhost:3000/?Token='+data)`.

I do not want to use the query string. Note `localhost:3000` is in other domain.If
it is in same domain then we can use localstorage, cookie but it is in
other domain. How can we achieve the goal without query string in
`reactjs`? Please assist me.

Comment: If you have control of what's on the other side of the window you could make it accept a POST http method and than pass all the data to your hearts content.

Comment: @Tyler I am not doing http get or post I am changing the location to other domain thats it.

Comment: Which be default is an http GET, all actions in the web have a request method associated with it, [Request Methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods)